# On the existence of finite substructures when sufficient chain conditions are met

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $L$ be a language and $T$ and $L$ theory. Suppose that for any $M\models{T}$, we have $M\subseteq{\bigcup{C_{n}}}$, where each $C_{n}\models{T_{\forall}}$ is finite. I want to show that for some finite subset $X$ of $M$, there is a finite $A\subseteq{M}$ such that $X$ is a subset of $A$.

This is related to the question: [Definition of Local Finiteness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617045/definition-of-local-finiteness)

I have tried to follow a similar proof, but here I run in to a problem; namely the substructure generated by $X$ maybe infinite inside of $M$ but (is necessarily) finite inside of $\bigcup{C_{n}}$. I'm not sure how to use the given conditions to obtain that this does not occur.

Edit 1) As per the comments below: A is a substructure of $M$ and the $C_{n}$ form a chain.

Comment: This is true if you assume that the $C_n$ form a chain $C_0\subseteq C_1\subseteq C_2 \dots$ (more generally a directed system). If the $C_n$ are just any finite substructures of $M$, the proposition could be false (for example, it's possible that every substructure generated by one element has only one element - then $M$ is contained in the union of all of its one-element substructures - but any substructure generated by two elements is infinite). Also, I think you want to stipulate that $A$ is a substructure of $M$, not just a subset, right?

Comment: @AlexKruckman: We can assume that the $C_{n}$ form a chain. I will add it as edit. But I'm still having the same issue. Am I missing something fundamental here? I don't see why being a chain would immediately yield an answer (It could be that all elements of the chain have extra elements not in $M$).

Also I don't know if you noticed, but I wrote $\subseteq$ for substructure above, and subset out as a word whenever it's a subset :) It has always bugged me that you overuse the symbol $\subseteq$ in model theory.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice your convention. I tend to use $\subseteq$ for subset, and add the word "substructure" when the context demands it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X$ is finite, there is some $n$ such that $X\subseteq C_n$ (note that this also works when the $C_n$ form a directed system instead of a chain). Now let $A$ be the substructure generated by $X$. Since $C_n$ and $M$ are structures containing $X$, we have $A\subseteq C_n$ (so $A$ is finite) and $A\subseteq M$.

You wrote "the substructure generated by $X$ may be infinite inside of $M$ but (is necessarily) finite inside of $\bigcup C_n$". I'm not sure I understand the issue here. But if it's not already clear to you, you should check that if $X$ is a subset of $A$, which is a substructure of $B$, then the substructure of $A$ generated by $X$ is equal to the substructure of $B$ generated by $X$.

Comment: Also, note that you might as well assume that $M = \bigcup_n C_n$, by replacing each $C_n$ with $C_n \cap M$, which is a substructure of $C_n$ and $M$ and hence a model of $T_\forall$.